# How do you enter the hollow mossy grotto in the Anwen's Ambush quest on iPad?

Tags: ios, clash-of-heroes

This is the at the very beginning of the game where you are supposed to enter the grotto at the bottom right corner of the map (I googled for its exact location). I know how to enter the grotto on my Xbox but what sort of control do I use on iPad? I've tried tapping, double tapping, swiping left and right, and repeating 'open sesame' to no avail. Does anyone know?

Here is a pic of where I think the location of the hollow tree is.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried double-tapping on your character's location?

Comment: @rikitikitik I will give it a try. I just removed and reinstalled the game just in case it's a bug.

Comment: @rikitikitik You are absolutely correct. You'd think the game would give you some sort of hint. Can you make that into an answer?

Comment: I got stuck there as well. It is a bit unintuitive, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your character to do map transitions or enter buildings, move your character to where the transition should take place or to the entrance of the building. Once there, double tap that location.